# How to redirect after posting data to a url using php curl and header?

Tags: php, laravel

**Problem :** I am integrating  payumoney gateway in php-laravel.
I need a way to redirect user to payumoney test url after posting data to url.I am posting data using curl but not able to redirect user to url.
I dont wanna use js for this. Is there any solution for this in using php only?

Comment: Can you show us some code? It's hard to help you with more specific tips without.

Comment: in laravel there is litterly a `redirect()` function.

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting you have 2 alternatives:

1) Javascript, when you return from the php call. In an ajax callback for example.

2) From php send the *location* `header` with a redirect code (301, 302, 303) depending on your needs. Search here for *location header* there are many questions related.

This last option can also be acomplished with rewrite rules in the webserver. For example in Apache's .htaccess file.